# Persisting CheckBox State While Paging in Telerik RadGrid Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a telerik-radgrid where I use SelectAll. For SelectAll I have used checkbox. The checked status is going off after paging.
How can we persist the checked status of Checkbox can retained even after paging.

Comment: I'm assuming you specifically want to persist a user's choice while paging, which by default Telerik RadGrid uses a Postback.  However, they should have Ajax functionality or you can save all choices on the page event.  Then anchor to the event called by previous or next.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I may have tried something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Solved this one....

call checkChanged in checkbox OnCheckedChanged event
store checked value in viewstate and on item databond read the value of viewstate.

And here we have .cs code:-

public const string SELECTED_CUSTOMERS_INDEX = "UserIndex";

```
protected void CheckChanged(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox box = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)box.NamingContainer;
    var rowIndex = item.ItemIndex;
    var idex =  radStoreUsers.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues[rowIndex];
    string datakey = idex["Id"].ToString();
    if (box.Checked)
    {
        PersistRowIndex(datakey);
    }
    else
    {
        RemoveRowIndex(datakey);
    }
}

private void PersistRowIndex(string chkId)
{
    if (!SelectedCustomersIndex.Exists(i => i == chkId))
    {
        SelectedCustomersIndex.Add(chkId);
    }
}

private void RemoveRowIndex(string chkId)
{
    SelectedCustomersIndex.Remove(chkId);
}

private List<string> SelectedCustomersIndex
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState[SELECTED_CUSTOMERS_INDEX] == null)
        {
            ViewState[SELECTED_CUSTOMERS_INDEX] = new List<string>();
        }

        return (List<string>)ViewState[SELECTED_CUSTOMERS_INDEX];
    }
}

protected void radStoreUsers_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        CheckBox box = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkBox");
        if (item.OwnerTableView.DataMember == "Users")
        {
            if (SelectedCustomersIndex != null)
            {
                foreach(string id in SelectedCustomersIndex)
                {
                    if(item.GetDataKeyValue("Id").ToString() == id)
                    {
                        box.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```